# Python: List index Out of Range Error when list indexing

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list of lists `property_lists` which is structured as follows:

```
property_lists = [['Semi-Detached', '|', '', '2', '|', '', '2'], ['Detached', '|', '', '5', '|', '', '3'], ['Detached', '|', '', '5', '|', '', '5']]
```

and so on.

I am attempting list indexing in order to put all the elements into separate lists of their own.

For example:

```
typeOfProperty = [item[0] for item in property_lists]
```

returns

```
['Semi-Detached', 'Detached', 'Detached']
```

However, the below results in an `index list out of range` error:

```
bedrooms = [item[3] for item in property_lists]
```

But I don't understand why as each 'sub' list has 7 elements?

To be clear, i am trying to output:

```
['2', '5', '5']
```

Comment: When I run your code as presented, I get `bedrooms = ['2', '5', '5']`. I don't get an error.

Comment: The question is incomplete. `But I don't understand why as each 'sub' list has 7 elements?` Would you share the code how you get `property_lists`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The code outputs `['2', '5', '5']`. Do you have any more elements in `property_lists`?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg my full property_lists looks like this: https://pastecode.io/s/pg56vfyk I am quite confused as item[0] is the only key that works, item[1] and onwards all result in an out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

First can you please give example, of what you want in the output?

If you want the output like the below:

> propertyList1 = ['Semi-Detached', '|', '', '2', '|', '', '2']
> propertyList2 = ['Detached', '|', '', '5', '|', '', '3']
> propertyList3 = ['Detached', '|', '', '5', '|', '', '5']

then Here's the solution:

```
property_lists = [['Semi-Detached', '|', '', '2', '|', '', '2'], ['Detached', '|', '', '5', '|', '', '3'], ['Detached', '|', '', '5', '|', '', '5']]
    
propertyList1 = [items for items in property_lists[0]]
propertyList2 = [items for items in property_lists[1]]
propertyList3 = [items for items in property_lists[2]]
```

So what I am doing here is, I am taking the **property_lists** every index and creates its own list using list comprehension

You are taking the only first index of the **item** in your question, that's why it is the result list contains only "Semi-Detached" and "Detached" values.

AND

your second question is about the list index out of range, That is happening because you are running the for loop on the **property_lists**, and **item** variable will store the value that is coming from the property_lists,  so you cannot access the element with an index of the item. you can access the index-wise items after creating the separate lists like I created in the code.

Comment: I have just added a final line to my question. I am trying to output the 3rd element from all of the 'sub' lists in one list.

Comment: A quick way to do it is, like Yurvi Ginsbug explained in the answer  pList =  [item[3] if len(item) > 0 else 0 for item in property_lists]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your full data that referred in your comment https://pastecode.io/s/pg56vfyk.

One of the elements of `property_lists` has the the length of 1. That is `property_lists[8] = ['Land for sale']`.
You should have a check like this.

```
bedrooms =  [item[3] if len(item) > 2 else 0 for item in p]
```

Similar way for other indices > 0.